# Use Glass BSDF with emission Texture

Tags: rendering, materials, glass, emission

I have a glass material in front of a cube with an emission texture.
In render, the glass ignores the texture and I only see black.
How can you see emission texture through glass refraction ?

Here is a screenshot to show what is currently happenening (1 = Emission, 2 = Glass) :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a tag for the render engine so it's clear that this material is for Eevee or Cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eevee you have to tweak some parameters to have a correct transparency with glasses: Choose *Alpha Blend* in the material settings and also activate *Screen Space Refraction*:

[image]

Activate *Screen Space Reflections* and *Refraction* in the Render panel:

[image]

Also, deactivate the *Screen Space Refraction* of your emission object, you won't see an object that has *Screen Space Refraction* or *Alpha Blend* behind another one in Eevee .

Comment: I have it turned on, yet I still can't see through it.

Comment: please share your file (only keep the useful objects): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I added it in the main question

Comment: You need to also deactivate the *Screen Space Refraction* of your emission object, you won't see an object that has *Screen Space Refraction* behind another one in Eevee

Comment: Oh indeed ! Thank you